# Select unique random posting/recruitment places of employees within a list of places

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to select unique random posting/recruitment places of employees within a list of places, all the employees are already posted at the places, i am trying to generate a new random posting place for them with "where" condition that "employee new random location will not be equal to their home place"
Employee table is :

```
EmpNo   Empname           CurrentPosting    Home        Designation RandomPosting
1       Satish Kumar      Samastipur        Gazi        Manager     
2       Anil Kumar Singh  Vaishali          Patna       Manager     
3       Rajdev Prasad     Nawada            Gaya        PO      
4       Rajesh Kumar      Sheikhpura        Muzaffarpur PO      
5       Jitendra Kumar    Banka             Bhagalpur   Clerk
```

And so on...

And Places table is

```
PlaceID  PlaceName      Manager     PO    Clerk
1        Araria            2        0     1
2        Arwal             1        1     1
3        Aurangabad        1        0     2
4        Banka             2        1     1
5        Begusarai         1        1     1
6        Bhagalpur         1        1     2
7        Bhojpur           0        2     0
```

and so on...

i tried with rand() and newid() like as below,

```
select Employee.*, Place.PlaceName As RandomPosting  from Employee 
inner join Place on Place.PlaceID=Employee.EmpNo order by newid()
```

But unable to select what is required... that is to assign each Employee a PlaceName(from Place) randomly which is not equal to CurrentPosting and Home(in Employee).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for quick response, i didnt tried that , can u please comment that query... i m newbie in sql..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH cteCrossJoin AS (
    SELECT e.*, p.PlaceName,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.EmpNo ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RowNum
        FROM Employee e
            CROSS JOIN  Place p
        WHERE e.Home <> p.PlaceName
)
SELECT *
    FROM cteCrossJoin
    WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Joe, one issue .. i m getting only one record - first employee(EmpNo 1) with random new PlaceName exactly as required, how to get all the employees...

Comment: @MAX: I had a bug where I forgot the PARTITION BY clause. Have you tried it with that change?

Comment: Hi @Joe, I need your help again... how to to limit the random selection based upon designation numbers(in Places table)... that is to assign each Employee a PlaceName(from Places) randomly which is not equal to CurrentPosting and Home(in Employee) and Place wise designation will not exceed as given numbers.

Comment: @Joe I have posted this question at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544051/randomly-assign-work-location-and-each-location-should-not-exceed-the-number-of